# Json return in node js without express and any framework

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code is not working

```js
var http = require('http');

var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Its working as expected in my local system

Comment: Not enough info - no answer.

Comment: @Subburaj json not return

Comment: What does it return if not JSON?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    var http = require('http');
    var app = http.createServer(function(req,res){
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
    });
    app.listen(3000);
```

You should use curly brackets `{ }` for `Content-Type`.
Check [here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_http.asp)

Comment: close, its like: `{"context-type":"application/json"}`

Comment: @Gtm now check, There was a typo.

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov  I am trying this code but this retrun json string not a json type data retrun

Comment: @Gtm Please read what is `JSON`. And clarify what you need to get as output. Here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out it should return the json

```
function (req, res) {
    body = '';

    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    req.on('end', function () {

       var postBody = JSON.parse(body);

        var response = {
            "text": "Post Request Value is  " + postBody.value
        };

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: this code only return json string not a json format data retrun

Comment: I have updated the code above it now returns the json

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
var http = require("http");
let app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  console.log("------");
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
  res.write(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
  res.end();
});
app.listen(8080);
```

Run via node filename.js
then hit http://localhost:8080/  you will find Hello World!

Comment: but the OP is serving json not text

Comment: I can send a screenShot.

Comment: @AnkitKumarRajpoot this code retrun only json string not a json format data

Comment: For JSON u can use direct res.write({ a: 1 }); insstead of res.write(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));